# Unity display image at specific size

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, screen-size

We are working on a mobile application that requires a user to position a printed image on top of the touchscreen of his mobile device. The application should display a placeholder where the image has to be placed, with the correct size of the physical image, so we know exactly where it is in order to interact with it.

This works great on devices of which we know the exact screensize, but we want this to work on all mobile devices. Our developer who is working on this project appears to have problems to get the required information to do the calculations.

We are using Unity and it has to work on both iOS and Android. Can anyone give us some pointers on how to tackle this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the aspect ratio of the image by dividing the width by height.
2. Set a placeholder in the location it should be and give it a *fixed constant* height *OR* width.
3. If the height is fixed, multiply height by the aspect float to get the new width. If the width is fixed, divide the width by the aspect to get the new height.

Comment: The problem is not the calculation of the ratio of the image. It is that you cannot set a fixed constant height or width in exact millimeters using Unity.

Comment: You really need to be more specific with your problem. All you said was that you were having trouble placing a placeholder for an image. Unity canvas coordinates are pixel coordinates, why cant you just set a fixed pixel size by finding out the mm : pixel ratio